# How to install SmartSVN in Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid Lynx)? JRE installation is suspected  

Tags: java, ubuntu-10.04, package-management, jre, smartsvn

I followed the instructions in *[How To: Install/Setup SmartSVN in Ubuntu](http://solyaris.wordpress.com/2007/07/26/how-to-installsetup-smartsvn-in-ubuntu/)*. I followed everything and it didn't start. I also tried to update my [JRE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Virtual_Machine#Execution_environment):

```
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jre sun-java6-plugin
```

But it does not work for me, because the terminal complains about package `sun-java6-jre` not being available, but is referred to by another package.

This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source. Error message:

> Package sun-java6-jre has no installation candidate

I did run [Synaptic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synaptic_%28software%29), so I managed to install Java JRE, I think. But I cannot view JRE on Chrome using the test applet [Othello](http://www.w3.org/People/mimasa/test/object/java/Othello).

So I think I did not successfully install JRE hence my Chrome and my [SmartSVN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SmartSVN) are not working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Sun Java packages are not available in the default Ubuntu repositories. You need to enable Canonical's partner repositories.  After following the below procedure they should be available:

1. Open System -> Administration -> Software Sources
2. Switch to the "Other Software" tab.
3. Enable the repository with this listing:
   `http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu lucid partner`
4. Update your Apt cache; either in Synaptic (press the Reload button), or on the commandline (`sudo aptitude update`).
5. Now the packages should be available in Synaptic or via your installation command.  You can also use this *aptitude* variation:
   `sudo aptitude install sun-java6-jre sun-java6-plugin`

Comment: thanks.

at least i got my chrome java applet working. however my smart svn is still not working. any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Get sun-java-jdk by adding a third-party PPA:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ferramroberto/java`
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk`